# ArchUnit rule to check Integration Test location

Tags: archunit

I want to write an ArchUnit rule that check that classes having a name ending with IT must be located in the ingreationTest module.

Looking at the API it seems that is only possible to check the package and not the folder/module where a class is located.

I'm using gradle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what to *"be located in the ingreationTest module"* means to you, but can probably make use of [`JavaClass`'s `getSource()` method](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.1.0/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaClass.html#getSource()), which tells where this class has been imported from.

For example:

```java
classes()
    .that().haveSimpleNameEndingWith("IT")
    .should(be(describe("located in the 'ingreationTest' module", javaClass ->
        javaClass.getSource()
            .map(source -> source.getUri().getPath().contains("ingreationTest"))
            .orElse(false)
    )))
```

I'm using the following static imports:

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.describe;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchConditions.be;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.classes;
```